# How to use $store in my mixins file in Nuxt js app

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I declared myMixins.js file in "mixins" directory.
Also declared myStore.js file in "store" directory.

**myStore.js** looks something like that:

```
export const state = () => ({
    name:null
});

export const mutations = {
    setName(state, value){
       state.name = value;
}

export const getters = {
    getName(state){
       return state.name;
    }
}
```

**myMixins.js** looks something like that:

```
export default {
    methods: {
       getName: function () {
           return this.$store.getters['myStore/getName'];
       }

  }
}
```

I get an error relating the $store.
How do I refer the store?
Thank you

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: @Pradeepb I'm getting undefined

Comment: please post the error screenshot or error message. what is undefined? $store ?

Comment: @Pradeepb you are right sorry:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getters' of undefined

Comment: You are able to use store in other components? Because above code is working for me

Comment: @Pradeepb Yes of course. This functions like the mixins getName() works when it inside a component. I get access to "this.$store"

Comment: @Pradeepb Can you provide the code in a component that calls the mixins getName method?
Maybe I have a mistake

Comment: I hope this helps https://pastebin.com/cUNqr0xm

Comment: @Pradeepb You are great. Thank you so much!
I had an error in the way I referred the mixins In my components!

Comment: that's great. happy to help.